# Browser back not working after pagination and parameter change in url

Tags: jquery

I need to maintain previous url on back button click but I am not able to do that. Following is the scenario:

Step 1: Homepage
Step 2: Clicked on Support page (http://dev.bca.com/en/support) 
Step 3: From global search, I searched for Technology and it redirected me to following url with parameters:
 http://dev.bca.com/search?query=Technology&index=0&size=25&languages=English#all

Now when I click on browser back, it should go back to step 2 page. But it's not working.

Please suggest.

Comment: URL is not working

Comment: See the history, maybe there are multiple redirect between step 2 and step 3.